# Add multiple home servers to one subnet

Tags: windows-home-server

Is it possible to have more than one Windows Home Server on the same subnet?

I have used WHS at home.  When I setup the connector software, I have never seen it ask which machine to connect to (of course I only have one server).  Now, I am considering deploying a couple of WHS machines at my office and was wondering how the connector chooses the correct server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Why wouldn't you be able to?

edit: when you have multiple WHSs on the same subnet, the connector software asks which you want to connect to. You have also use Discovery.exe in the WHS program files to change which one you are associated with.